# Dangers of shopt

Tags: bash

In another question it was suggest that I use

```
shopt -s extglob
```

To fix a problem. I get the impression that these type commands are to be used sparingly, perhaps because they can have ill effects with other scripts. Can anyone speak to this?

Comment: I can't imagine it would cause any problems: the extglob syntax would produce an error if that option is off.

Comment: Switching it on globally might break the occasional script... If you use it within a script (and the script is run, not sourced), the setting only affects that shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shopt` only affects the behavior of the shell that that command is run in. If you put it in `~/.bashrc` then, it will affect non-login interactive shells and commands run over rsh/ssh (login shells may also be affected if `~/.bashrc` is sourced in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`).

Setting the environment variable `BASHOPTS` to `extglob` will affect all interactive or non-interactive bash shells started while that environment variable is set (unless they're called as `sh`).

Interactive shells are where you want to have `extglob` set because that's where you want to use it, so `~/.bashrc` is a good place to put it to benefit from it in every interactive shell. If you want to use it in a script, just add it at the start of the script.

The only place where that could cause problem is when it is set while some code that you didn't write doesn't expect it to be set. That could be for instance scripts that you *source* at the prompt or in `~/.bashrc` after you've set the option.

While that is true for some options, it is not for `extglob` as it was carefully designed (by David Korn as that comes from ksh) so as not to break backward compatibility with the Bourne shell (and explains why the syntax is so awkward).

Basically, anything using extended globs would be a syntax error in the Bourne shell or in the POSIX shell syntax. If a Bourne or POSIX script had `echo @(a)`, it would be broken (because of the unquoted parenthesis). It wouldn't matter if all of a sudden it started to output "a" instead of an error message.

Why bash doesn't enable it by default is not clear to me, given that bash doesn't have any other alternative extended glob syntax of its own like zsh does.

**EDIT**. While David Korn tried hard not to break Bourne/POSIX compatibility, it looks like bash wasn't so careful and is probably why it's not enabled by default like in ksh.

In ksh (and zsh in ksh emulation), the extended globbing operators are disabled when performing globbing upon parameter or command substitution:

```
$ touch a
$ a='@(a)' ksh93 -c 'echo $a'
@(a)
```

While in bash, it's not the case:

```
$ a='@(a)' BASHOPTS=extglob bash -c 'echo $a'
a
```

Comment: So your recommendation is not to enable `extglob` in `~/.bashrc`?